# How to remove duplicate objects from a list based on a certain field but add a quantity before removing?

Tags: java, collections

I have an assembly class having multiple fields.

I need to remove duplicate objects of the assembly class from a list of assembly objects based on assembly code, but before removing I need to add the assembly quantity to the matched assembly object's quantity.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new ArrayList<>();

        assemblies.add(new Assembly("abc1", 3.0));
        assemblies.add(new Assembly("abc2", 6.0));
        assemblies.add(new Assembly("abc3", 8.4));
        assemblies.add(new Assembly("abc4", 9.0));
        assemblies.add(new Assembly("abc1", 4.2));
        assemblies.add(new Assembly("abc1", 6.3));

        System.out.println("List with duplicates: "+assemblies);

        HashSet<String> assmCode=new HashSet<>();
        assemblies.removeIf(e->!assmCode.add(e.getAssemblyCode())); //remove the last two abc1

        //but i need to add 4.2, 6.3 to 3.0 before removing
        System.out.println("List without duplicates: "+assemblies);
    }
}

class Assembly{
    private String assemblyCode;
    private double assemblyQty;
    //There will be more such fields

    public Assembly(String assemblyCode, double assemblyQty) {
        this.assemblyCode = assemblyCode;
        this.assemblyQty = assemblyQty;
    }

    public String getAssemblyCode() {
        return assemblyCode;
    }

    public void setAssemblyCode(String assemblyCode) {
        this.assemblyCode = assemblyCode;
    }

    public double getAssemblyQty() {
        return assemblyQty;
    }

    public void setAssemblyQty(double assemblyQty) {
        this.assemblyQty = assemblyQty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Assembly{" +
                "assemblyCode='" + assemblyCode + '\'' +
                ", assemblyQty=" + assemblyQty +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I can do an operation of such before removing the duplicate objects. I am new to java's collection api, so sorry for asking the question if the solution is easy.

Just to clarify, the output must be like this:

List with duplicates: [Assembly{assemblyCode='abc1', assemblyQty=3.0}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc2', assemblyQty=6.0}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc3', assemblyQty=8.4}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc4', assemblyQty=9.0}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc1', assemblyQty=4.2}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc1', assemblyQty=6.3}]

List without duplicates: [Assembly{assemblyCode='abc1', assemblyQty=13.5}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc2', assemblyQty=6.0}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc3', assemblyQty=8.4}, Assembly{assemblyCode='abc4', assemblyQty=9.0}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to remove duplicate objects of the assembly class from a list
>   of assembly objects based on assembly code, but before removing I need
>   to add the assembly quantity to the matched assembly object's
>   quantity.

Yo need to keep duplicates values to be able to reuse them.
 `removeIf()` will not capture this information.

You could use an iterator to remove elements and introduce a Map variable to store the duplicate information :

```
Map<String, Double> assemblyDupMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Iterator<Assembly> it = assemblies.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
      Assembly a = it.next();
      if(!assmCode.add(a.getAssemblyCode())){ 
         // store the duplicate information 
         double currentQty = assemblyDupMap.getOrDefault(a.getAssemblyCode(), 0D);
         assemblyDupMap.put(a.getAssemblyCode(), currentQty + a.getAssemblyQty()); 
         // remove it from the list
         it.remove();        
      }

};
```

Then update the quantity :

```
assemblies.forEach( a -> Optional.ofNullable(assemblyDupMap.get(a.getAssemblyCode()))
                                 .ifPresent(qty -> a.incrementQty(qty))
                  );
```

As you can notice, it is verbose enough. Essentially because we need to update the elements of the list.
If creating a new list instead of using the existing is acceptable, the stream approach is more concise.

Group the objects by their assembly code in a Map, sum their quantity by code and keep only the objects as result:

```
new ArrayList<>(assemblies.stream()
                          .collect(toMap(Assembly::getAssemblyCode, o -> o,
                                         (a, b) -> new Assembly(a.getAssemblyCode(),
                                                                a.getAssemblyQty() + b
                                                                    .getAssemblyQty()),
                                         LinkedHashMap::new)
                          )
                          .values());
```

For the record, summing `double`s can produce an  "undesirable" result. `BigDecimal` may interest you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, I used your 2nd method where it's not verbose. Just one correction, I had to write Collectors.toMap for it to work. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. About the correction, in fact, I didn't add the imports. I generally use static imports for collectors to make the code more readable.